# c++ bad access error on find()

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I am getting a bad access error while trying to find days between two dates given as a string. I found that the maximum number of days that my function will find is 1884 but I don't know why. The bad access error is in the a.find("/") function call.

Here is the code. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
int daysBetweenDates(string a, string b) {
if (a == b) {
    return 0;
}
cout << a << endl;
int month = stoi(a.substr(0, a.find("/")));
a = a.substr(a.find("/")+1);
int day = stoi(a.substr(0, a.find("/")));
a = a.substr(a.find("/")+1);
int year = stoi(a);

int k = 0; // days in the month;
if (month == 2) {
    k = year%4==0 ? 29 : 28;
}
else if ((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) {
    k = 30;
}
else {
    k = 31;
}


day++;
if (day > k) {
    month++;
    day = 1;
}

if (month > 12) {
    year++;
    month = 1;
}

string new_a = to_string(month) + "/" + to_string(day) + "/" + to_string(year);

return 1 + daysBetweenDates(new_a, b);
}
```

Comment: You probably see stack overflow, due to a very deep recursion. Yours is probably the least efficient solution possible. At the very least, that recursion can be trivially replaced with a loop.

Comment: First thing to do: find the minimum code necessary for reproducing your problem.

Comment: All the `a.find("/")` uses should also check against `std::string::npos` in case the string is not found.

Comment: @Eljay  -- maybe, but that's a design decision: it's not at all unreasonable to validate the form of the input before calling this function, and if that's done, then this function doesn't have to check for failures.

Comment: Define a `Date` structure and use that instead of messy (and error-prone) string operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive calls are eventually causing a stack overflow.  Change the code to remove the potentially deeply nested calls.  For example, by changing the routine to use a loop.  C++ compilers typically do not do tail recursion optimization.